How to statically generate a page in Next.js app router
I am using Next.js App Router.
I have a page /blogs that should display the titles of all the blogs. I am using markdown for the blogs and they are stored inside blog-content folder of src folder. And I am getting the blog posts from within the project folder i.e. they are not stored in a database. So, I am not using fetch
I am able to generate each blog page /blogs/[blog] statically using generateStaticParams but I also want to generate the entire list of all blogs statically as well.
In pages router, I would use getStaticProps but this approach does not work in App Router.
How would I do this in app router?
This is my page.
import Link from 'next/link';
import React from 'react'

import type { Post } from '@/lib/md';
import { getAllPublished } from '@/lib/md';

const BlogsPage = () => {
  const posts:Post[] = getAllPublished("src/blog-content");

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Blog Posts</h1>
    {posts.map((post:Post) => (
      <div key={post.slug}>
        <p>[ {post.frontmatter.tags.join(", ")} ]</p>
        <Link href={`blogs/${post.slug}`}>
          <a>{post.frontmatter.title}</a>
        </Link>{" "}
        <p>{post.frontmatter.description}</p>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
  )
}

export default BlogsPage

Right now, when I run the application, the posts array is empty.
When I run run build I see that /blogs/[blog] is SSG but /blogs is SSR.
